# Typedef statement

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Using `typedef` statement allow us to create a new type of of data with giving type, for example `typedef NSString *String;`

I also able to treat a new type like `NSString`:

```
    typedef NSString *String;
    String myString = @"Programming is";
    NSLog(@"%@", [myString stringByAppendingString:@"cool"]);
```

My question is - am i not able to use class methods? Following code produce an error:

```
    String newString = [[String alloc]init];
```

Error says: `Receiver type 'String' (aka 'NSString') is not an Objective-C class`

But with `typedef` statement we getting the same NSString object (in my understanding) with both class methods and instance methods. Instance methods work fine, class methods not work.

Why is that happen?

Comment: Using a typedef to alias the name of a framework class is a terrible idea, by the way.

Comment: @jlehr I'm doing only in purpose of studying language features :)

Comment: Excellent, otherwise I would've been worried for you.  :-)

Comment: @jlehr no worries)) Btw is there any particular case when using typedef convenient?

Comment: Cocoa frameworks typically use typedef statements for C structs and enums, as well as for certain primitive types in order to provide better portability (for example, `NSInteger` and `CGFloat`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that when you say:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^
```

you are using two different types, `NSString *` and `NSString`. So you either need two typedefs:

```
typedef NSString String;
typedef String *StringPtr;

StringPtr newString = [[String alloc]init];
```

or one typedef and make the indirection explicit:

```
typedef NSString String;

String *newString = [[String alloc] init];
```

Comment: Your code: typedef NSString String;
typedef NSStringPtr *StringPtr;

StringPtr newString = [[String alloc]init]; produce an error, second code snippet work fine, thank you. But what is the difference between NSString* and NSString?? Isn't * symbol is just declaration of pointer?

Comment: Sorry - there was a typo in the first example - fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Paul, i see how to fix it, but still no really understand what is the difference.. between NSString* and Nsstring.

Comment: `NSString *` and `NSString` are two distinct types - the first is a pointer type and the second one isn't. Consider `char *` and `char` - the first is a pointer to a character, whereas the second is an actual character.